# boost::asio throws exception when paused

Tags: c++, xcode, exception, boost-asio, breakpoints

I have a program that uses `boost::asio` to connect to a remote machine and then repeatedly prints out whatever it receives. The problem is, whenever I pause it or make any changes to the breakpoints while it's running, an exception is thrown from somewhere inside `read_until()`. Why does this happen and what should I do about it?

This is on a Mac running OS X 10.8.2 with Xcode 4.4.1 and Apple clang 4.0. Stack trace from when an exception was thrown after pausing the program:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1d07, 0x00007fff86bc9d46 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__kill + 10, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00007fff86bc9d46 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8ec40df0 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 177
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8c49ca17 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 257
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8c49a3c6 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate() + 28
    frame #4: 0x00007fff8d05e887 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 111
    frame #5: 0x00007fff8c49a3f5 libc++abi.dylib`safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #6: 0x00007fff8c49a450 libc++abi.dylib`std::terminate() + 16
    frame #7: 0x00007fff8c49b5b7 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw + 111
    frame #8: 0x00000001000043df test`void boost::throw_exception<boost::system::system_error>(boost::system::system_error const&) + 111 at throw_exception.hpp:66
    frame #9: 0x0000000100004304 test`boost::asio::detail::do_throw_error(boost::system::error_code const&, char const*) + 68 at throw_error.ipp:38
    frame #10: 0x0000000100004272 test`boost::asio::detail::throw_error(boost::system::error_code const&, char const*) + 50 at throw_error.hpp:42
    frame #11: 0x0000000100002479 test`unsigned long boost::asio::read_until<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >, std::allocator<char> >(boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >&, boost::asio::basic_streambuf<std::allocator<char> >&, std::string const&) + 73 at read_until.hpp:98
    frame #12: 0x00000001000012c5 test`main + 581 at main.cpp:21
    frame #13: 0x00007fff8983e7e1 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: looks like an untaught exception? Set a breakpoint at throw and figure out what type is thrown.

Comment: boost 1.51.0-stable. Ummm, how do I figure out what kind of exception it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_until()` has an override that will throw an exception on error, and if you aren't catching this then you will see this behavior. If you are using the `boost::asio` overrides that don't take in a `boost::system::error_code&`, then for safety you should wrap these calls in a `try` block that catches `const boost::system::error_code&`.  In the exception handler, you should examine the exception to see what the root cause of the failure is.

```
try
{
   boost::asio::read_until(...);
}

catch(const boost::system::error_code& err)
{
   // read_until(...) failed, the reason is
   // contained in err
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you pause your program, the actual pausing is accomplished by sending it a POSIX signal (`SIGSTOP`). One of the effects of this is that system calls (such as `read()`, which Boost will be using internally) return an error, `EINTR`. This is going to trigger `read_until`'s error handling code, which as you see, throws an exception.

If you want to handle this properly, you probably want to use the overload that takes a `boost::system::error_code` parameter, check `.value()` against `EINTR` (defined in `errno.h`), and retry your read.

This would look something like

```
boost::system::error_code error;
boost::asio::streambuf message;
do {
    boost::asio::read(socket, message, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(body_size), error);
} while (error.value() == EINTR);
```